# sent skype chat with python skpy with proxy

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy, skype

I have a Python code that works perfectly on my laptop. However, when I try to run it on my virtual machine with Windows, I need to set a proxy like this: `http://172.50.235.55:3428`. But I'm not sure how to change it. Can you please guide me on how to change the proxy settings on my virtual machine running Windows?
I had set proxy on Windows setting but it didn't work

```
from skpy import Skype
sk = Skype(username, password) # connect to Skype

sk.user # you
sk.contacts # your contacts
sk.chats # your conversations

ch = sk.chats.create(["joe.4", "daisy.5"]) # new group conversation
ch = sk.contacts["joe.4"].chat # 1-to-1 conversation

ch.sendMsg(content) # plain-text message
ch.sendFile(open("song.mp3", "rb"), "song.mp3") # file upload
ch.sendContact(sk.contacts["daisy.5"]) # contact sharing

ch.getMsgs() # retrieve recent messages
```

this  code return error `HTTPSConnectionpool (host='login.live.com', port=443)`

Also I tested this below code and got 'code 200'

```
 import requests

url = 'https://login.live.com'

proxy = 'http://172.50.235.55:3428'

proxies = {
    'http': proxy,
    'https': proxy
}

response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)

print(f'Status Code: {response.status_code}')
print(f'Response Content: {response.text}')
```

I want to use skpy like request with a proxy